# HTTP requests from Linux server CLI to a website with dynamic content that requires Webdriver (JS emulation)?

Tags: shell, wget, curl, selenium

Are there any simple solutions to making GET or POST requests from a CLI on a linux server to dynamically generated websites that require JavaScript to run in order to return HTML? I know that Selenium and Puppeteer exist but both seem a bit too big and bloated for my purpose. I don’t want to unit test or execute query selectors on generated HTML. I just want to make a request with desired headers and get back a response text in the shell like with curl or wget. If nothing viable exist, I guess Selenium and Python script is a possible way to go about it.

Comment: Curl ?      (filler here)

Comment: Curl does not emulate a browser to my knowledge, so when I tried, I got back a response from the website that I need to "enable JS".

Comment: Curl can set arbitrary headers and give you a text response -Are you sure the page is not using ajax or something to make additional server requests?

Comment: I finally figured out what was the issue. Site uses cloudflare and is blocking my curl request, even with cookies and all needed headers, I can't get through. Any way around it?

Comment: Did you set the User Agent string to pretend to be a graphical browser?  (eg per https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28760694/how-to-use-curl-to-get-a-get-request-exactly-same-as-using-chrome#31597823 )? What makes you think this is related to Cloudflare? If it is Cloudflare  you have likely triggered their DDoS protections - but the error that wpuld return would surely be different?